# DataColumn Name from DataRow (not DataTable)

Tags: c#, .net, datarow, datacolumn

I need to iterate the columnname and column datatype from a specific row. All of the examples I have seen have iterated an entire datatable. I want to pass a single row to a function to do a bunch of conditional processing. I want to separate the conditional processing for ease of readability.

This is what I have:

```
private void doMore(DataRow dr)
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in dr.ItemArray)  //loop through the columns. 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(c.ColumnName.ToString());
    }
}
```

The error returned is

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Data.DataColumn'.

How would I get the column name from the row or do I have no choice and must pass the entire datatable to the function?

Comment: Do you just really want to show column or data in row?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You would still need to go through the `DataTable` class. But you can do so using your `DataRow` instance by using the [`Table`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.table.aspx) property.

```
foreach (DataColumn c in dr.Table.Columns)  //loop through the columns. 
{
    MessageBox.Show(c.ColumnName);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can make it easier in your code (if you're doing this a lot anyway) by using an extension on the DataRow object, like:

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static string GetColumn(this DataRow Row, int Ordinal)
    {
        return Row.Table.Columns[Ordinal].ColumnName;
    }
}
```

Then call it using:

```
string MyColumnName = MyRow.GetColumn(5);
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed.  Geez.  Wasted hours on that before your help.  The "Row.Table.Columns[Ordinal].ColumnName;" was the part I didn't get at first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need something like this:

```
foreach(DataColumn c in dr.Table.Columns)
{
  MessageBox.Show(c.ColumnName);
}
```

Answer (score -7):

use DataTable object instead:

```
 private void doMore(DataTable dt)
    {
    foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
    MessageBox.Show(dc.ColumnName);
    }
    }
```

Comment: -1: The OP specifically said that he only wants to pass a `DataRow` to his method.