# Getting all column names / column values from datarow when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm creating a mock instance of one of my datarows for testing.

The row I'm trying to duplicate from our database contains 37 columns with different variables.

Is there any chance when debugging to get the information out in clean text for simple editing of my mock objects?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823371/datacolumn-name-from-datarow-not-datatable Best Answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
var colNames = dr.Table.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)
                               .Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToList()
```

Answer (score 10):

I had to adjust Nikhil's Cast:

```
var colNames = dr.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().Select(x => x.ColumnName).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it like this since I couldnt get Nikhils code to work.

```
        int i = 0;
        while(i<looprow.Table.Columns.Count)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(looprow.Table.Columns[i].ColumnName);
            i++;
        }
```