# Dataset column name and row value

Tags: c#, dataset, sqlclient

I have a data set:

```
DataSet ds= _ExecuteQuery(contentCmd, CommandType.Text, contentParams);

// Column name
foreach (DataColumn column in ds.Tables[0].Columns)
{
  Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
}

// Rows value
foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables){
     foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows){
        Console.Writeline(dr.Table.Rows[0]["name"].ToString());
     }
}
```

How can I retrieve rows value and column name of the row?

```
List<columnName, name>;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DataColumn Name from DataRow (not DataTable)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12823371/datacolumn-name-from-datarow-not-datatable)  Doesn't they look alike?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that you're looking for something like this:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> vals = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                vals.Add(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName, dr[dt.Columns[i].ColumnName].ToString());
            }
        }
```

Depends on your dataset, but this gives a full dictionary of each column name and corresponding value